# How do I add form select option to php rss feed script

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to add a dropdown list to an RSS feed parser.

I have this:

```
<fieldset class="rsslib">

<?php
$cachename = "rss-cache-tmp.php";
$url = "http://www.theweekinchess.com/twic-rss-feed"; 

if(file_exists($cachename))
{
    $now = date("G");
    $time = date("G", filemtime($cachename));
    if($time == $now)
    {
        include($cachename);
        exit();
    }
}
require_once("rsslib.php");
$cache = RSS_Display($url, 15, false, true);
file_put_contents($cachename, $cache);
echo $cache;
?>
</fieldset>
```

But I want to to set the $url in php with a select option like so:

```
<?php

$temp = $_POST["url"];

?>

<form method = "post">  
<select name="url" id="url">
<option value="http://www.theweekinchess.com/twic-rss-feed">TWIC</option>
<option value="http://chesscafe.com/feed/">Chess Cafe</option>
<option value="http://www.chessdom.com/rss">Chessdom</option>
<option value="http://chess-news.ru/rss-eng">Chess-news</option>
<option value="http://www.chess.com/rss/articles">chess.com</option>
</select>
</form>
```

But I can't pass the form variable to the php script. I tried but my results were pathetic and I wanted to leave the original code to simplify things.

Any ideas?

Comment: just use that `$temp` as your url inside `RSS_Display`

Answer (score 0):

Your form needs an action.

You need to know if the form was submitted: ($sub)

```
<?php
$sub = intval( $_POST["sub"]);  
if ($sub == 1){ 
  $url= $_POST["url"];
}
else{
  $url = "http://www.theweekinchess.com/twic-rss-feed"; 
}
require_once("rsslib.php");
$cache = RSS_Display($url, 15, false, true);
$cachename = "rss-cache-tmp.php";
file_put_contents($cachename, $cache);



// I have no idea what you are doing here or why

if(file_exists($cachename)){
  $now = date("G");
  $time = date("G", filemtime($cachename));
  if($time == $now){
    include($cachename);
    exit();
  }
}


echo <<<EOT
$cache;
<fieldset class="rsslib">  // ??????

</fieldset>
<form action="#" method = "post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1" /> 
<select name="url" id="url">
<option value="http://www.theweekinchess.com/twic-rss-feed">TWIC</option>
<option value="http://chesscafe.com/feed/">Chess Cafe</option>
<option value="http://www.chessdom.com/rss">Chessdom</option>
<option value="http://chess-news.ru/rss-eng">Chess-news</option>
<option value="http://www.chess.com/rss/articles">chess.com</option>
</select>
</form>
EOT;
?>
```